# How to include the output of a stored procedure in a select

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

I have a table with 3 date columns:

```
TAB1
col_1    col_2     col_3
```

col_2 and col_3 are used to prepare inputs to a stored procedure TRANSFORM():

```
Tcol_2:=col_2;
Tcol_3:=col_3;

TRANSFORM(Tcol_2 IN OUT date,Tcol_3 IN OUT date);
```

How do I include the values returned by the stored procedure (Tcol_2 and Tcol_3) in the select of TAB1?

Conceptually I wish to have the output of TAB1 along with the transformed values of col_1 and col_2 (namely Tcol_2 & Tcol_3):

```
select col_1,col_2,col_3,Tcol_2,Tcol_3 from TAB1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, not the way it is now.

`TRANSFORM` should be a **function** if you want to use it in `select` statement. If it transforms `col_2` and `col_3` in the same manner, then it is simpler to do it. Otherwise, function will need another parameter (to distinguish which one to transform), or use two functions.